# PHP работа с бд

Tags: mysql, php, база-данных

Попробую максимально донести суть вопроса, т.к. я  в этом деле новичок. :)
В общем, есть меню (табс):

[image]

Вот вкладка "общие". Там выводятся названия постов, которые относятся к категории "общие".

Сделал я это таким способом:

> index.php

> ```
>   <div id="viewnews">
>         <div class="newsStyle"><h1>Категории постов</h1></div>
>         <div class="tabs" >         
>             <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabwin">
>                 <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Общие</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Фильмы</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Музыка</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">www</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">SMS</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#tab-5" data-toggle="tab">Картинки</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#tab-6" data-toggle="tab">Видео</a></li>
>             </ul>
>             <div class="tab-content">
>                 <div class="tab-pane fade  in active" id="tab-1">
>                     <?php include ('action.php'); ?>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-2">
>                     <?php include ('action2.php'); ?>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-3">
>                     <?php include ('action3.php'); ?>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-4">
>                     <?php include ('action4.php'); ?>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-5">
>                     <?php include ('action5.php'); ?>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab-6">
>                     <?php include ('action6.php'); ?>
>                 </div>
>             </div>              
>         </div>
>         <div class="WinNews">
>         <p class="newsStyle">Последний добавленный пост</p>
>             <?php include ('view_news.php'); ?>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

А вот код:

[action.php](http://jsfiddle.net/gm2mz812/)

Ну как бы я понимаю, что отдельно файл для каждой категории создавать (типа action1.php action2.php action3.php...) как-то глупо. :) Вот хотелось бы узнать, как воплотить идею.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вот именно из-за этого плюются в **php**-разработчиков.

Comment: @IamS, с тем же успехом можно назвать этого человека js-программистом или верстальщиком. На саммом деле web-мастер, на первой ступени своего развития, и в этом нет ни чего плохого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте один файл, который будет выводить все категории:

```
$types = ['Общие', 'Фильмы', 'Музыка'];
foreach ($types as $typeId=>$typeName) {

    echo '<div class="tab-pane fade  in active" id="tab-'.$typeId.'">';
    $strSQL = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE categoryPost="'.$typeName.'"';
    $rs = mysqli_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
        echo '<a href="#" style="color:#c09853;letter-spacing:1px;">' . $row[2] . "</a><br />";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

Прекращайте читать старые примеры, где используется модуль mysql - он устарел. Используйте [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).